# How do I debug app without access to a PC?

Tags: android, debugging, android-debug

My app keeps crashing on start despite AIDE (which I use as an IDE) saying no errors. During the week I don't have access to a PC so I am stuck with just my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For production environment, you shall collect crash reports from your users by using a library like  **ACRA** (Application Crash Reports for Android ) https://github.com/ACRA/acra which allows you to send crash reports to any destinations.

You can add your own log file extracts as well as logcat, eventlog or radiolog to reports.

Also See [BasicSetup](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup) and [AdvancedUsage](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage).

Comment: Ok so got it all setup, however, can't seem to get it to do anything. I tried to set it up for email but on crash I get nothing. I'm probably doing something wrong...lol

Answer (score 2):

Crashlytics works really well for me. It can be found at https://www.crashlytics.com/. Its extremely easy to add into your app then it will log all crashes and error found from any device that your app is installed on. The error reports can be found online or they can automatically be emailed to you. The crash reports have the exact line number where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Try below, works for me.

> aLogcat is the well-known developer tool logcat, in the form of an
>   Android application.
>
> View color-coded, scrolling (tailed) Android device (logcat) logs
>   directly from your phone. No USB, adb, or emailing necessary.
>
> Set log format / level / buffer, filter logs by regex, clear log file,
>   save to SD.
>
> Share logs via any application that handles plain text or HTML
>   sharing, including Gmail, Email, Pastedroid, Bluetooth, and others.
>
> Install application Pastedroid to share logs via pastebin. Ensure HTML
>   output is disabled in preferences as this only supports plain text
>   logs.
>
> Optionally save log files at specified intervals in the background.

https://code.google.com/p/alogcat/downloads/list

Comment: Not sure how to get the log files for that?

Comment: @GalacticGhost in application, press more button(three dots) and press Preferences. At the bottom, there is an option as Periodic Save and you can change the frequency. Also you can save the logs manually as .txt of course.